# What would be the most addictive substance it is possible to make?

Tags: science-based, biochemistry

The year is 2085, and by this time a few new drugs, or variations on old drugs, have been created.

As far as I know, the most addictive substance is heroin. However, my universe requires an even more addictive substance. How could this be achieved?

Mixing drugs, heightened concentrations, incredible lethality, all are allowed.

This drug must be topical, a single exposure to the drug must be enough for the taker to then, without notion of restraint, take it until they die.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what your goal is.  There are a fair number of ways to make chemicals more potent/addictive if we know what your endgame is we can probably better answer this.

Comment: You should describe in which ways heroine is not addictive enough. Do you want to people to become addicted faster, or make it harder to quit, or increase their potential while using the drug, or decrease their potential, ...?

Comment: @Secespitus Faster addiction, harder to quit, extreme compulsion.

Comment: https://www.addictioncenter.com/community/these-are-the-5-most-addictive-substances-on-earth/

Comment: Do you just need a physical addiction, or you actually need hallucinogenic effect or another way to alter the mind and perception? Because just by going with "Faster addiction, harder to quit, extreme compulsion." as description, I can tell you that nothing can beat oxygen. What exactly do you want your superdrug to achieve? Drugs are not taken for some nebulous simplistic eeeevil. They are taken as a form of escapism, as performance enhancers or other similar reasons. At some point, every junkie had a reason. You can't gloss over like that, because it makes concept of drug pointless.

Comment: Is physical or psychological dependence more important to you? Oxygen is perfect physical dependence you can't live without it but you can override your desire for it, at least for a time. The wire is perfect psychological dependence your body does not need it in the slightest but you are incapable of choosing not to do it just based on how the brains decision making works.

Comment: What are you looking to do with the answers?  It sounds like you know the exact effects you want to see, how much biochemistry do you really need to back it up?

Answer (score 5):

Air/Oxygen is pretty addictive. If in doubt, try taking it away from someone for a couple of minutes and see what happens...

Alternatively, in terms of sci-fi, I'd look at it this way: its presence saturates the dopamine AND oxytocin receptors and gives the user more energy, high arousal, and heightened awareness/ sensitivity to external stimuli, as well as a general sense of euphoria and diminished long-term memory storage (what happens in Vegas, stays in Vegas).

Withdrawal from the drug causes insomnia, major anxiety, paranoia, tachycardia, spikes in blood pressure, autoimmune system attack, and therefore incredible pain.

This would certainly require a cocktail of drugs, some of which have very long residence times (say by accumulating in fat). MDMA and Heroin, alcohol and nicotine are examples.

I'd say the drug could start off with a "high" (high energy, high awareness, high sensitivity) and then change into euphoria and finally a barbiturate-like mellowness. If more isn't used withing a day or two (period shortens as addiction increases) withdrawal symptoms start.

Comment: At what point did you stop talking about oxygen, and start talking about the new drug?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on, how we measure the "addictivity". Other answers focus on the general addictivity of a material, for example "air" is very-very addictive in this sense.

But you have to use a lot of air. People have to use kilograms of air in every day. A single kg of [LSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lysergic_acid_diethylamide) is an unimaginable quantity (miligrams are needed for a standard dose).

If we calculate the addictivity *per mass*, then probably some LSD derivative, or some protein reaction catalyst would be the "best" (worst).

Another possibility: **a genetical modificated virus which actually produces an addictive drug in your body**. From such a virus, a single "cell" would be enough to make a some week long trip from it. If we want to talk about addiction, it should be a virus against which your immune system can adapt.

After the adaption, the virus dies out in the body of the "drug" user, and thus his/her internal drug supply stops. To "trip" again, he needs a new infection - another single cell of the virus, but with a little bit different protein coating. Thus, he has again some weeks "high", until his(her) immune system adapts again.

According to [this](https://futurism.com/how-to-weigh-a-virus-2/) page, a typical virus size is around $10^{-15} g$.

The current virology probably doesn't known any virus who could produce a mind-affecting drug in the body of the host user, but they would be possible.

Side remark: actually, viruses doesn't produce anything. They build themself into the cells of the host (either into the DNA, or into the RNA), and modify their protein synthesis to do what they want (which is, in most cases, to stop its ordinary work, and replicate the virus cells instead).

Comment: LSD isn't addictive.

Comment: @Mazura It is not true. One of my friends said roughly 6 weeks long drive for a next "travel" after his first (and only) try.

Comment: "Several other classes of drugs are categorized as drugs of abuse but rarely produce compulsive use. These include psychedelic agents, such as lysergic acid diethylamide (LSD), which are used for their ability to produce perceptual distortions at low and moderate doses. The use of these drugs is associated with the rapid development of tolerance and the absence of positive reinforcement (Chapter 6)."

Comment: "Partial agonist effects at 5HT2A receptors are implicated in the psychedelic actions of LSD and related hallucinogens. 3,4-Methylenedioxymethamphetamine (MDMA), commonly called ecstasy, is an amphetamine derivative. It produces a combination of psychostimulant-like and weak LSD-like effects at low doses. Unlike LSD, MDMA is reinforcing—most likely because of its interactions with dopamine systems—and accordingly is subject to compulsive abuse."

Comment: However, I was only 98% right ;) - "Hallucinogen abuse and dependence are known complications resulting from the illicit use of drugs in this category, such as LSD and psilocybin. Users do not experience withdrawal symptoms, but the general criteria for substance abuse and dependence otherwise apply. **Dependence is estimated in approximately 2 % of recent-onset users in the United States.**"

Comment: @Mazura I don't believe this. Marijuana is addictive, you said it is not. All of these "drug is not addicting/dangerous/harmful" are the lies of the worst criminals of the world history. They should be shot, all of them, and not Pablo Escobar. The real drug lords aren't in Columbia, they are in the U.S. government, and they say you in your U.S. TV that "drugs are not addictive"...

Comment: Your buddy was either on ecstasy or is one of the 2%.

Comment: @Mazura Not true. The 2% is a lie.

Answer (score 0):

'Religion is the opium to man'. - karl max
So as you can see, we are addicted not only to a substance, but it may be to a concept, a person or an organisation that you are addicted to.

First we have to understand why we are addicted to something, someone or some concepts.

Any thing that causes happiness results in the secretion of a neurohormone called dopamine from our hypothalamus. So basically you can say dopamine is the 'happiness hormone'. When you do drugs, for example, your body's dopamine level increases and stays there temporarily, and sets the yardstick of your body's dopamine desire to be higher than normal, and then falls.
But your body is now attuned to the dopamine level already reached, and now you have to restock it again and again, and you get addicted.

Now this can be anything that gives you happiness.

My suggestion: Give them a drug that lets them envision what they yearn for most. Like the mirror of Harry Potter.

You can read the 'Reality Bug' of the Pendragon series to get a hang of my concept.